# Convert li input values data to JSON 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

Hello I need to save multi values and update database using ajax.. I'm working on Yii framework..

in the first I need to send data using ajax as json but I have wrong on results.

Live code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kxJwp/2/

My javascript code is:

```
$("#save").live('click', function(){
    var showtimes = [];
    var values = {};
    $('li inputs').each(function() {
        values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        showtimes[i]=values;
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(showtimes));
});
```

**Javascript output:**

*It's output last one li values x number of li*

**inputs:**

```
<li>
    <input name="show_id" class="show_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="movie_id" class="movie_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="cinema_id" class="cinema_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="status" class="status att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="times" class="timesArray att" type="hidden" value="" />
<li>
<li>
    <input name="show_id" class="show_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="movie_id" class="movie_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="cinema_id" class="cinema_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="status" class="status att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="times" class="timesArray att" type="hidden" value="" />
<li>
```

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting to get? a full code?

Comment: no no just javascript code.. and thax

Comment: There's no question here! The js refers to table elements and html is list elements. Be specific about what it is you want, what works and doesn't work, and make the html and js match

Comment: There's nothing about PHP in this, you should remove that tag.

Comment: you made a minor code adjustment but have not explained in detail what you need

Comment: +1, updated my answer, i think it should work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing only one row because you have only one object, whereas you need an array of objects, so declare an array first, and then keep adding the objects to it. Something like this:

```
$("#save").live('click', function(){
  var showtimes = [];    // Create empty javascript array
  var objec={};
  $("li").find("input").each(function(index) {           // Iterate over inputs

    objec=new Object; // to create a new object for every matched element

    objec[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val()+'avla';
    showtimes[index]=objec;  // Add object to array
  });

  var json = JSON.stringify(showtimes);
  alert(json);
});
```

Code explanation:
Use the inbuilt [index of `each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), by passing the index to the function like: `function(index){...}`.

Edit: `objec=new Object;` is needed to avoid getting repeated values, because each time the same object was getting added to the array, but with new, a new object is created each time and that is added to the array.

**Update:** A better way to select the `li`s would be using a selector such as : `$("li:has(input)")` and then cycle through the children:

```
$("#save").live('click', function(){
    var showtimes = [];
    var values = {};
    $("li:has(input)").each(function(i){
        values = new Object;
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            values[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val();
        });
        showtimes.push(values);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(showtimes));
});
```

Edit: The output(arrays formed) in both the above samples is different.

Output for code sample 1:

```
json=[{"show_id":"1avla"},{"movie_id":"2avla"},{"cinema_id":"3avla"},{"status":"4avla"},{"times":"5avla"},{"show_id":"6avla"},{"movie_id":"7avla"},{"cinema_id":"8avla"},{"status":"9avla"},{"times":"0avla"}]
```

Output for code sample 2:

```
json=[{"show_id":"1","movie_id":"2","cinema_id":"3","status":"4","times":"5"},{"show_id":"6","movie_id":"7","cinema_id":"8","status":"9","times":"0"}]
```

Comment: Ok man that is good.. but this code show only first <li> values in json repeated many times.. why ?

Comment: oh, i hadn't seen that, i hadn't checked with values, that's why i was just appending 'avla' random string. anyway lemme check, and get back to you

Comment: ok, i do see it happening, only the last set of `li`s are getting inserted repeatedly, let me try and fix that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12250/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-abudayah)

Comment: glad that it worked, if you are looking to give the bounty, then you have to manually award it, check [here award bounty manually](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty), otherwise i have to wait for 7 days!! which is long!

Comment: @booldev it's told me I still 12 hour to give the bounty

Comment: oh, sorry i forgot about that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your original js code shows

```
$("tr").find("input.att").each(function() {
```

however your view code shows you are using an `<li>` instead of `<tr>`

So shouldn't it be `$("ul") or $("li")`

Comment: in fact it's table and I've simplified my code.. I edited thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use another alternate method. The changes you should made is place the the `li`s and `input'`s under a form ad submit the form via ajax. Also you should change the names of the input according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) ie add square brackets so that you can retrieve it as arrays in PHP. No jSON needed
So

```
    <form id="myform" action="action.php">
    .....
    <li>
        <input name="show_id[]" class="show_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="movie_id[]" class="movie_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="cinema_id[]" class="cinema_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="status[]" class="status att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="times[]" class="timesArray att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <li>
    <li>
        <input name="show_id[]" class="show_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="movie_id[]" class="movie_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="cinema_id[]" class="cinema_id att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="status[]" class="status att" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="times[]" class="timesArray att" type="hidden" value="" />
    <li>

    ....

</form>
```

and the javascript for ajax

```
$("#save").live('click', function(){
    var form = $('#myform');
    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } );


});
```

then in your controller you will get the submitted data as **array**

```
print_r($_POST['show_id']);
print_r($_POST['movie_id']);
```

etc etc